# Arduino yun strange uploading error

Tags: arduino-yun

I'm new to arduino and I'm trying to upload a fairly large (I think) program to a arduino yun which includes a 3 dimensional array. I'm using the bridge features of the yun.

when I upload the first time after unplugging and plugging back in again it runs fine. When I try and upload a second time I get the following error regardless of which code I'm trying to upload (blink example for example)

```
 avrdude: verification error, first mismatch at byte 0x0000
 0xff != 0x0c avrdude: verification error; content mismatch
```

In the serial monitor I get the following output:

```
Unable to connect: retrying (1)... 
Unable to connect: retrying (2)... 
Unable to connect: retrying (3)... 
Unable to connect: retrying (4)... 
Unable to connect: is the sketch using the bridge?
```

I'm currently developing as much as I can in another sketch but it's a pain.
I can provide the code if needed.

Thanks for any help